# Making a Calculator which take input from user until user enter 0 but not working correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, calculator

I am a newbie in python and trying to make a calculator but no getting how to make it
I am making a Calculator which will take input from the user until the user enters 0 and then do the operations
but I am stuck here
if anyone can help me doing this work I will be very thankful to him/her.

```
num = None

# Asking Users for the Specific Operations

print(("1. For Addition \n 2. For Subtraction. \n 3. For Multiplication. \n 4. For Division \n 5.For Exit"))

options = int(input("Enter Your Choice: "))

# For Addition or Option 1

if options == 1:
    total = 0
    while(num != 0):
        try:
            num = float(input("(Enter \'0'\ When Complete.) Enter Number "))
        except:
            print("Error, Enter Valid Number")
            continue
        total = total + num
    print("Your Calculated Number is: {} ".format(total))

# For Subtraction or Option 2

elif options == 2:
    total = 0
    while (num != 0):
        try:
            num = float(input("(Enter \'0'\ When Complete.) Enter Number "))
        except:
            print("Error, Enter Valid Number")
            continue
        total = total - num
    print("Your Calculated Value is: {}".format(total))

# Multiplication for Option 3

elif options == 3:
    total = 1
    while (num != 0):
        try:
            num = float(input("(Enter \'0'\ When Complete.) Enter Number "))
        except:
            print("Error, Enter Valid Number")
            continue
        total = total * num
    print("Your Calculated Value is: {}".format(total))

# Division for Option 4

elif options == 4:
    total = 1
    while (num != 0):
        try:
            num = float(input("(Enter \'0'\ When Complete.) Enter Number "))
        except:
            print("Error, Enter Valid Number")
            continue
        total = total / num
    print("Your Calculated Value is: {}".format(total))

# When User Wants to Exit

else:
    print("Thank You for Using the Calculator")
```

Comment: Subtraction won't work, because you never assigned an initial value to `total` in that block of code.  If there's some other problem, you need to tell us what it is - if an error was generated, we expect the full traceback message; if it's just unexpected results, we need to see what you received, and what you expected.

Comment: I have changed the code of Subtraction by adding total = 0 but there is a problem when user input the first number my code subtract the number from total which is zero and due to this my code is giving me negative value at first then subtracting other negative value will add both number

Comment: when i have to subtract 3 from 5 the answer should be 2 but my code gives me -8 because 0-5 = -5 and then -5-3 = -8 thats the problem I dont want it to minus from 0 at first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
elif options == 2:
    total = 0
    while (num != 0):
        try:
            num = float(input("(Enter \'0'\ When Complete.) Enter Number "))
        except:
            print("Error, Enter Valid Number")
            continue
        total = total - num
```

use (the changes are only in the *2<sup>nd</sup>* line and in the *last* one)

```
elif options == 2:
    total = None
    while (num != 0):
        try:
            num = float(input("(Enter \'0'\ When Complete.) Enter Number "))
        except:
            print("Error, Enter Valid Number")
            continue
        total = total - num if total is not None else num
```

---

The same method you may use for the `elif options == 4:` branch.

Comment: Thanks a alot for your help

Answer (score 1):

Here is a better approach using [`itertools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce). Instead of repeating the same code for inputting a number multiple times, put it into a function. This will also help avoid the errors in your code and clarify the logic. A second generator function can be used to get the series of values until the user enters zero.

```
from functools import reduce
import operator

def input_number():
    while True:
        try:
            return float(input("(Enter '0' When Complete.) Enter Number "))
        except:
            print("Error, Enter Valid Number")
        
def input_series():
    while True:
        n = input_number()
        if n == 0:
            return
        yield n

operations = {
      1: operator.add,
      2: operator.sub,
      3: operator.mul,
      4: operator.truediv
      }
# Asking Users for the Specific Operations
print(("1. For Addition \n 2. For Subtraction. \n 3. For Multiplication. \n 4. For Division \n 5.For Exit"))
option = int(input("Enter Your Choice: "))

# For Addition or Option 1

if option == 5:
    print("Thank You for Using the Calculator")
else:
    total = reduce(operations[option], input_series())
    print("Your Calculated Value is: {}".format(total))
```

Comment: I am using Pycharm and it is giving me Import Error 'Cannot import name ' reduce' from 'itertools'(location unknown)

Comment: sorry should be `functools` - have corrected the code

Answer (score 0):

The problem with subtraction is that the variable `total` is not initialized.

The problem with multiplication and division is that when the user inputs "0", the variable `total` is multiplied or divided by zero before it is checked in the while statement. what I would normally do is this:

```
elif options == 3:
total = 1
while True:
    try:
        num = float(input("(Enter '0' When Complete.) Enter Number "))  # No need to escape single quotes when your string uses double quotes 
        if num == 0:
            break
    except ValueError:
        print("Error, Enter Valid Number")
        continue
    total = total * num
print("Your Calculated Value is: {}".format(total))
```

However, if you wanted a quick fix, you can have the user input 1 instead of 0 for multiplication and division:

```
elif options == 4:
total = 1
while (num != 1): 
    try:
        num = float(input("(Enter '1' When Complete.) Enter Number "))
    except:
        print("Error, Enter Valid Number")
        continue
    total = total / num
print("Your Calculated Value is: {}".format(total))
```

Edit: If you want division to work the way you specified, you could do something like this:

```
elif options == 2:
    total = 1
    try:
        first_number = float(input("(Enter '0' When Complete.) Enter Number "))
        if first_number == 0:
            print("Your Calculated Value is: 0")
            exit()
    except ValueError:
        print("Error, Enter Valid Number")
        continue

    total = 1
    while True:
        try:
            num = float(input("(Enter '0' When Complete.) Enter Number "))
            if num == 0:
                break
        except ValueError:
            print("Error, Enter Valid Number")
            continue
        total = total * num
    print("Your Calculated Value is: {}".format(total + first_number))
```

Comment: when i have to subtract 3 from 5 the answer should be 2 but my code gives me -8 because 0-5 = -5 and then -5-3 = -8 thats the problem I dont want it to minus from 0 at first – Saad_Ali786 just now   Edit   Delete